# ContentTemplateSelector does not work after view is activated

Tags: winui-3

I read with interest the question posed by Joe Wang last November on this subject. I have a similar and frustrating issue:

The xaml in the Page...

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ServerSelectionTemplate" 
        <views:ServerSelectionControl />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ReplicaSetSelectionTemplate"
        <views:ReplicaSetSelectionControl />
    </DataTemplate>

    <local:ConnectionPageTemplateSelector x:Key="contentTemplateSelector" 
        SelectServerTemplate="{StaticResource ServerSelectionTemplate}" 
        SelectReplicaSetTemplate="{StaticResource ReplicaSetSelectionTemplate}"/>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
...
    <ContentControl
        Grid.Row="2"
        Margin="0,5,0,5"
        Content="{x:Bind ViewModel}"
        ContentTemplateSelector"{Static Resource contentTemplateSelector}">
    </ContentControl>
...
</Grid
```

... and the selector class code

```cs
public class ConnectionPageTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate SelectServerTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate SelectReplicaSetTemplate { get; set; }
    
    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item) => SelectTemplateCore(item, null);

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (null == item)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var viewModel = (ConnectionPageViewModel)item;

        if (viewModel.SelectedConnectionType == 0)
        {
            return SelectServerTemplate;
        }

        if (viewModel.SelectedConnectionType == 1)
        {
            return SelectReplicaSetTemplate;
        }

        return SelectServerTemplate;
    }
}
```

The view model is derived from ObservableRecipient and everything else in it works fine.
The DataTemplateSelector function is called when the view is activated, twice in fact, the first time item is null, as expected and the second time with a reference to the view model.  And that is the only time the selector function is called!  Nothing I have done will trigger a call to the SelectorTemplateCore function.

Have I missed something stupid (won't be the first time) or am I the victim of a more subtle problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think that `x:Bind` is your problem. `x:Bind` is `Mode=OneTime` by default. Try setting it to `Mode=OneWay`.

```xml
<ContentControl
    Grid.Row="2"
    Margin="0,5,0,5"
    Content="{x:Bind ViewModel, Mode=OneWay}" <-HERE
    ContentTemplateSelector"{StaticResource contentTemplateSelector}">
</ContentControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Andrew KeepCoding for making me think!  I had, erroneously, assumed that the SelectDataTemplate function would be called when any property of the view model changed.  Obviously, in my case, it would be called when the view model itself changed.  I overcame the issue (twice) using the message service and code behind, not very elegant!  I have now bound the content control to an enumeration by which the view model selects the user control required.  I am sure this will offend MVVM purists but in the absence of style triggers I really see no alternative.  It works and has reduced the amount of code that other solutions required and there is nothing in the code behind (yet)!

For the MVVM purists I can only say that there are times when the view model MUST know what the view is doing.  But I was raised on MSDOS, Dbase and Clipper; so what do I know.  Respect to KeepCoding and keep thinking.